# ColdFusion 10 License Issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I installed ColdFusion 10 Enterprise Edition 64 bit. But after 30 days it is converted into Developer edition automatically. Now when i try to give new KEY through System Settings, it displays the message "Server has been updated successfully" but it still shows in the System Settings that it is "Developer Edition" and i am getting following error message when more than 2 persons try to access the ColdFusion applications on the server

"You tried to access the Developer Edition from IP address (192.1.221.83). Already two IP addresses are accessing ColdFusion concurrently. The Developer Edition supports access by any IP address, but only two at a time, apart from the localhost. The additional IP addresses accessing ColdFusion are: 192.1.221.5,192.168.0.168"

Can anyone help on that please? When i am giving the KEY why it isn't converting it into Enterprise edition?

Comment: Perhaps it requires a restart after applying the key. Have you tried that?  Check the logs to see if any errors are being reported when applying the key.

Comment: @Miguel-F There are no errors in logs. And I already tried resetting. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure it out
I had to move back to CF9

Comment: Did you talk to Adobe support?

Comment: No, my website was down so I had to fix it ASAP. Instead of spending time to communicate with them I moved back to CF9 again.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to take advantage of the [free installation support Adobe offers](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/free-coldfusion-installation-support-from-adobe). Email: cf.install@adobe.com.

I've heard of this sort of thing happening before, but am unaware of a generic answer. But Adobe will sort it out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your good advise. But my website was down so I had to fix it ASAP. Instead of spending time to communicate with them I moved back to CF9 again.